# Altium Leaves Board Border Outline on Assembly Notes Layer

Tags: pcb, altium

No matter what, Altium leaves a border of the board on my cover page when I try to generate an assembly document. I only have two layers: Assembly cover notes and Assembly notes tops. Neither of which have a board outline on them. How do I remove this outline?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What layer is the outline coming from?

There's a checkbox output option to copy certain layer(s) onto all output plots.

"Mechanical Layer(s) to add to all Plots". Maybe the layer with the outline is checked.

Comment: The layer that the outline is coming from is multilayer. However, the option you suggested is unchecked. I posted a sort of hack like solution after getting off the phone with altium.

Answer (score 1):

Found a sort of hack like solution after calling Altium:

"Under PCB printout properties select the layer and right click select preferences and under color and grayscales, select multilayer and put it to white."

-Altium Guy

Comment: A hack indeed, but worth noting for future reference.